# Facebook/Javascript: sending a user ID var to the database

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've got a function which returns a User ID (of a user who has logged in to the site using Facebook).

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //logging the User ID here....
        console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
    }
});
```

Later in the script I fire off an Ajax with a bunch of vars that I've received.

```
 multiUploader.prototype._uploader = function(file,f){
    if(typeof file[f] != undefined && self._validate(file[f].type) > 0){
        var data = new FormData();
        var ids = file[f].name._unique();
        data.append('file',file[f]);
        data.append('index',ids);
        data.append('title', $(".giveawayNameInput").val());

        $(".dfiles[rel='"+ids+"']").find(".progress").show();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:this.config.uploadUrl,
            data:data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(rponse){

                console.log(rponse);
                //Spinner can be removed here...
            }
        });
    } else
        alert("Invalid file format - "+file[f].name);
}
```

Where I do `data.append()` I'd like to append the User ID I've received from the first function. How can this be achieved without defining`response.authResponse.userID` as a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling FB.getLoginStatus  inside function(file,f) need to declare local varaible inside function(file ,f) which hold response value out of FB.getLoginStatus  scope and make available in scope of function(file,f).